# Laravel dynamic whereHas

Tags: php, eloquent

I am trying to run a query through a relationship path. In human readable format:

```
Get collection of orders where $order->orderItem->product->sku is LIKE 'red-jumper';
```

I can create this manually using a whereHas query as follows:

```
$query->whereHas('orderItems', function($query) use($request){
    $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) use($request){
        $query->where('sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
    });
});
```

However, if I want this to be dynamic and do not know the amount of levels in the relationships, how can I do this?

I would be looking for something lik:

```
$paths = [
0 => 'orderItems'
1 => 'product,
2 => 'sku'
];

$query->whereHas($paths[0], function($query) use($request, $paths){
    $query->whereHas($paths[1], function ($query) use($request, $paths){
        $query->whereHas($paths[2], function ($query) use($request, $paths) {
            $query->whereHas($paths[3], function ($query) use ($request, $paths) {
                $query->where('sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slightly better way in my opinion. You can use dot (.) notation for relationships and collections to turn your $path array into what you want. First we reduce the $path to a dotted relationship and separate the attribute you want to filter by later

```
$path = ['orderItems', 'product', 'sku']
$param = array_pop($path)
// $path = ['orderItems', 'product']
// $param = 'sku'
$dotPath = collect($path)->reduce(function ($c, $i) {
    return $c . $i . '.';
});
// $dotPath = 'orderItems.product.'

$dotPath = substr($dotPath, 0, -1)
// $dotPath = 'orderItems.product'
```

And then we check with `whereHas`

```
$query->whereHas($dotPath, function ($query) use ($request, $param){
    $query->where($param, 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
})->get();
```

Comment: I just realized the whole collect()->reduce part was a bit overkill. You can just implode the array and get the same result. `implode($path, '.')`

Comment: I am actually starting with a dot path and making into the array path, so I can skip that step all together